# Error in Gurobi for optimization?

Tags: ampl, gurobi

```
sw: ampl
ampl: include Availability1.ampl
Gurobi 5.5.0: mipgap = 0.00000000000000000000000001
outlev = 1
Optimize a model with 68298 rows, 1934 columns and 28751 nonzeros
Presolve removed 1934 rows and 68298 columns
Presolve time: 0.02s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    9.9948451e-01   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s
     179    9.9948451e-01   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s

Solved in 179 iterations and 0.06 seconds
Optimal objective  9.994845101e-01
Gurobi 5.5.0: optimal solution; objective 0.9994845101
179 simplex iterations
```

Above is my output: No error but is not the optimal answer.
What's the matter? I can't get the right answer. Please help me.

Comment: "Presolve: All rows and columns removed"  occurs.

Comment: What makes you think the answer is not optimal? Do you know a better answer, and can prove it's feasible?

Comment: From my theory, the intern variable should have values not 0. Because in my theory, there is spare capacity for the transmission. And whether has this kind of potential that the solver GUROBI has a limited computational ability causing the appearance of the error or not?