# presolved in MILP

Tags: ampl, gurobi

Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    9.9086144e-01   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s
      16    9.9086144e-01   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      0s

Solved in 16 iterations and 0.00 seconds
Optimal objective  9.908614362e-01
Gurobi 5.5.0: optimal solution; objective 0.9908614362
16 simplex iterations

whats the problem and I cannt find it for two weeks. I can test the model right under small network data file. But when I test under larger network with more nodes, it occurs this kind of problems shown above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in Gurobi for optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497217/error-in-gurobi-for-optimization)